# PHPWord how to wordwrap text?

Tags: php, phpword

I currently have an issue tested in Word2007, Word2013 and it is working fine in LibreOffice.

I have text coming from mysql database inside cells and it doesn't respect the line breaks.

Example in Word2007: 

text = - car - plane - sofa - office

Example in LibreOffice (Ubuntu 16 LTS):

- car

- plane

- sofa

- office


I have found an option inside PHPWord `'wordWrap'=>true` but doesn't seems to have any effects.

Have someone encounted that issue and could give me a working example please?

**EDIT**: Trying first solution inside table with cells. **(The code below is inside a while loop so it recreate 10 times the cell if there is 10 \n)**

```
$table->addRow($height);
$table->addCell($width, $styleVertical)->addText("$risques_identifies", $styleTextNextRow, $styleLeft);
$table->addCell($width, $styleVertical)->addText("$epi_epc", $styleTextNextRow, $styleLeft);

$table->addCell($width, $styleVertical);
$textlines_organisation_documentation=explode("\n",$organisation_documentation);
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($textlines_organisation_documentation); $i++) {
$table->addText("$textlines_organisation_documentation", $styleTextNextRow, $styleLeft);
}
```

My code create an error. I don't know how to create a cell and add the text after (inside the "for"). This is what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will insert a line break for each paragraph defined by `\n`:

**Edit (thanks @CBroe)**:

```
$text = "foo\nbar\nfoobar";
$textlines = explode("\n", $text);

// Create table...
// Add table cell
$mycell = $table->addCell()

// Loop content to append cell
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($textlines); $i++) {
    $mycell->addText($textlines[$i]);
}
```

Comment: That solution is working fine with pure text good point. I don't know how to addapt it inside a table with cells. I have edited my question for show you my code and give you in details what i'm trying to archive. It's probably nothing but i'm not familiar with object coding i'm used to do the old way. Thanks

Comment: @BackTrack57: In your code you are calling addText once on a cell – where is the problem doing it multiple times, exactly the same way as molivier suggested …?

Comment: @CBroe ah good point ! I've forget to say this code is inside a while loop so it recreate 10 times the same cell and gives me a huge table. I add this detail in question. Thanks

Comment: Create the table cell once (`$mycell = $table->addCell()`), and then use a loop over the splitted text parts, and inside that loop call `$mycell->addText` for each part.

Comment: @CBroe Great ! This is working ! Thanks a lot ! If you want you can create an answer explaining it again and I accept it.

Comment: @molivier: I don’t think it is a “better” answer, it is basically just what you suggested, adapted to the specific situation of the OP (basically all it needed was to replace `$section` with a reference to a table cell created before) – so you deserve the credit :) Feel free to edit my suggestion into your answer though, if you feel that makes it better.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your very nice comment. SO should implement collective answer :) I'm honored to edit my answer with your complement.